# SQL Server - Use while loop to shorten several Union Joins

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query that I simplified. Simply it displays a list of counts of records in the last 4 weeks.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Counts], Week=1
    FROM TableA
    WHERE Date >= DATEADD(week,-1,GETDATE())
      AND Date <= GETDATE()
    UNION
    SELECT COUNT(*), 2
    FROM TableA
    WHERE Date >= DATEADD(week,-2,GETDATE())
      AND Date <= DATEADD(week,-1,GETDATE())
    UNION
    SELECT COUNT(*), 3
    FROM TableA
    WHERE Date >= DATEADD(week,-3,GETDATE())
      AND Date <= DATEADD(week,-2,GETDATE())
    UNION
    SELECT COUNT(*), 4
    FROM TableA
    WHERE Date >= DATEADD(week,-4,GETDATE())
      AND Date <= DATEADD(week,-3,GETDATE())
```

Returns:

```
----------------
| Count | Week |
----------------
|   20  |   1  |
----------------
|   10  |   2  |
----------------
|   30  |   3  |
----------------
|   25  |   4  |
----------------
```

Suppose I want to modify the query so it returns the last 10 or 20 weeks.

How can I shorten the query so it loops through weeks?

e.g.

```
declare @w int;
set @w = 10;
while @w <> 0
begin
    ...; 
    --how can I do union joins?
    set @w = @w - 1;
end
```

Comment: Doing this in a loop is completely the wrong direction.

Comment: @SeanLange Why do you say so?

Comment: Because we want to avoid loops. This is known as RBAR (row by agonizing row) and it is horribly inefficient and slows down sql incredibly. Loops are useful and even required for a few administrative tasks and a small handful of other situations. This is definitely not one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could avoid `UNION` and specifying each week by hand by using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT datepart(week, Date) AS WeekNum, COUNT(*) AS counts
FROM TableA
WHERE Date >= DATEADD(week,-20,GETDATE()) -- num of weeks
GROUP BY datepart(week, Date);  -- week of the year
```

If you need nums from 1 to n then:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT datepart(year, Date) AS [year], 
           datepart(week, Date) AS WeekNum, 
           COUNT(*) AS counts
    FROM TableA
    WHERE Date >= DATEADD(week,-20,GETDATE()) -- num of weeks
    GROUP BY datepart(year, Date), datepart(week, Date)
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [year] DESC, WeekNum DESC) AS WeekNum, counts
FROM cte;
```

**EDIT:**

> *"yes, like if today is wednesday, 20 week will give you a week starting in wednesday"*

It could be handled by:

```
WHERE Date >= DATEADD(week,-20,GETDATE())
 => 
WHERE Date >= DATEADD(week,-20,
           CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE()) AS DATE))
```

Comment: yes, like if today is wednesday, 20 week will give you a week starting in wednesday

Comment: @sgeddes Ok, now it is going  backwards with ROW_NUM

Comment: nvm looks like OP doesnt mind because he do the same on his query.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza This is actually good point, I will handle it with an edit

Comment: You don't have to answer this but suppose the week started on Thursday or some arbitrary weekday. Would there be a simple way to modify this or should I ask another question?

Comment: @BDillan I believe you could use [SET DATEFIRST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for current session to set it up. [DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=09e0ff8763f219c573f16240c18a1949) and from DATEPART: `Week and weekday datepart arguments

For a week (wk, ww) or weekday (dw) datepart, the DATEPART return value depends on the value set by SET DATEFIRST.`

Comment: Thank you. Il try using that